# How to compare integer values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am writing a program that needs to read a csv/text file with football scores that looks like this:

```
Lions 3, Snakes 3 
Tarantulas 1, FC Awesome 0 
Lions 1, FC Awesome 1 
Tarantulas 3, Snakes 1 
Lions 4, Grouches 0
```

If the teams draw, each team gets 1 point, if a team wins they get 3 points.

The output should ideally look like this:

```
1. Tarantulas, 6 pts 
2. Lions, 5 pts 
3. FC Awesome, 1 pt 
3. Snakes, 1 pt 
4. Grouches, 0 pts
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd


data = pd.read_csv("sample_input.csv", header=None, names=['left_team', 'right_team'])
data_dict = data.to_dict(orient='list')


def splitter(row):
    left_team, right_team = row.split(',')
    return {
       'left_team': left_team[:-2].strip(),
       'left_score': int(left_team[-2:].strip()),
       'right_team': right_team[:-2].strip(),
       'right_score': int(right_team[-2:].strip())
}
```

My question is how do I get the data fram the dataframe to compare the values? I have also tried coding the solution without pandas but I am struggling with that. Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

This is the other solution that I have tried:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv


reader = csv.DictReader(open('sample_input.csv', 'r'))

dict_list = []

for line in reader:
    dict_list.append(line)


data_list = [splitter(row) for row in reader]


def splitter(row):
    left_team, right_team = row.split(',')
    return {
       'left_team': left_team[:-2].strip(),
       'left_score': int(left_team[-2:].strip()),
       'right_team': right_team[:-2].strip(),
       'right_score': int(right_team[-2:].strip())
}


data_dicts = [splitter(row) for row in reader]


team_scores = defaultdict(int)

for game in data_dicts:
    if game['left_score'] == game['right_score']:
        team_scores[game['left']] += 1
        team_scores[game['right']] += 1
    elif game ['left_score'] > game['right_score']:
        team_scores[game['left']] += 3
    else:
        team_scores[game['right']] += 3


teams_sorted = sorted(team_scores.items(), key=lambda team: team[1], reverse=True)

for line in teams_sorted:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a straightforward solution. The first step cleans the data and then just assigns points to each team. At the end you add together all of the points for each team, regardless of whether they appear on the left or right.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create DataFrame from your input
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=', ', header=None)
df.columns=['l_team', 'r_team']

# Clean the data, separating teams and their score. 
df[['l_team', 'l_score']] = df.l_team.str.extract('(.*)\s(\d+)')
df[['r_team', 'r_score']] = df.r_team.str.extract('(.*)\s(\d+)')
df[['l_score', 'r_score']] = df[['l_score', 'r_score']].astype('int')
```

Now `df` looks like:

```
       l_team      r_team  l_score  r_score
0       Lions      Snakes        3        3
1  Tarantulas  FC Awesome        1        0
2       Lions  FC Awesome        1        1
3  Tarantulas      Snakes        3        1
4       Lions    Grouches        4        0
```

Determine how many points the teams on the left or right scored and add together by team. We use `Series.add` so it's aligned on index, which after the `groupby` is just the team name.

```
df['l_pts'] = np.select([df.l_score > df.r_score, df.l_score == df.r_score], [3, 1], 0)
df['r_pts'] = np.select([df.r_score > df.l_score, df.r_score == df.l_score], [3, 1], 0)

scores df.groupby('l_team').l_pts.sum().add(df.groupby('r_team').r_pts.sum(), fill_value=0).astype('int').sort_values(ascending=False)
```

Output: `scores`

```
Tarantulas    6
Lions         5
Snakes        1
FC Awesome    1
Grouches      0
dtype: int32
```

To exactly match your output, you could do something like:

```
pd.Series(scores.index+', '+scores.values.astype('str')+' pts', index=np.arange(1,len(scores)+1,1))
#1    Tarantulas, 6 pts
#2         Lions, 5 pts
#3        Snakes, 1 pts
#4    FC Awesome, 1 pts
#5      Grouches, 0 pts
```

Comment: For some reason my output is different. My values are 6, 4, 1, 0, 0. The only thing I changed was read_clipboard to read_csv. Any idea why this is happening? The dataframe has the correct values so it could be the sum that is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

No magic here. Just define a function that translates the scores into points, apply it, unpivot the left/right-ness, and group by team and sum the points. There may be a more elegant solution.

Prepare the data using your function:

```
data = '''Lions 3, Snakes 3 
Tarantulas 1, FC Awesome 0 
Lions 1, FC Awesome 1 
Tarantulas 3, Snakes 1 
Lions 4, Grouches 0'''

def splitter(row):
    left_team, right_team = row.split(',')
    return {
       'left_team': left_team[:-2].strip(),
       'left_score': int(left_team[-2:].strip()),
       'right_team': right_team[:-2].strip(),
       'right_score': int(right_team[-2:].strip())
}

data = pd.DataFrame(splitter(row) for row in data.split("\n"))
print(data)

Out:
       left_score   left_team  right_score  right_team
0           3       Lions            3      Snakes
1           1  Tarantulas            0  FC Awesome
2           1       Lions            1  FC Awesome
3           3  Tarantulas            1      Snakes
4           4       Lions            0    Grouches
```

Add columns of the teams' points using their scores

```
def points(left_score, right_score):

    win_points = 3
    draw_points = 1
    lose_points = 0

    if left_score < right_score:
        return pd.Series({'left_points': lose_points, 'right_points': win_points})
    elif left_score > right_score:
        return pd.Series({'left_points': win_points, 'right_points': lose_points})
    else:
        return pd.Series({'left_points': draw_points, 'right_points': draw_points})

data = data.merge(
    data[['left_score', 'right_score']].apply(lambda row: points(*row), axis=1),
    left_index=True, right_index=True
)
print(data)

Out:
   left_score   left_team  right_score  right_team  left_points  right_points
0           3       Lions            3      Snakes            1             1
1           1  Tarantulas            0  FC Awesome            3             0
2           1       Lions            1  FC Awesome            1             1
3           3  Tarantulas            1      Snakes            3             0
4           4       Lions            0    Grouches            3             0
```

Unpivot:

```
data = pd.concat([
    data[['left_team', 'left_points']]\
    .rename({'left_team': 'team', 'left_points': 'points'}, axis=1),
    data[['right_team', 'right_points']]\
    .rename({'right_team': 'team', 'right_points': 'points'}, axis=1)
])

print(data)

Out:
         team  points
0       Lions       1
1  Tarantulas       3
2       Lions       1
3  Tarantulas       3
4       Lions       3
0      Snakes       1
1  FC Awesome       0
2  FC Awesome       1
3      Snakes       0
4    Grouches       0
```

Group by to get final result:

```
result = data.groupby("team")["points"].sum()
print(result)

Out:
team
FC Awesome    1
Grouches      0
Lions         5
Snakes        1
Tarantulas    6
Name: points, dtype: int64
```